# android statement do not execute after setText in TextView

Tags: android, textview

i am developing a small application in android. my activity_main consists of three things Button ,TextView and ImageView

and here is the code of main activity

```
package com.example.shiv.facedetection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.FaceDetector;
import android.media.FaceDetector.Face;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onthetapbuttonclick(View View){
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try{
            Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1);

            Bitmap bitmap565 = bp.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);


            if((1==(bitmap565.getWidth()%2))){
                bitmap565 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap565,
                        bitmap565.getWidth()+1, bitmap565.getHeight(), false);
            }




            FaceDetector fd = new FaceDetector(bitmap565.getWidth(),bitmap565.getHeight(), 4);
            Face[] faces =new Face[4];
            int i =fd.findFaces(bitmap565, faces);
            TextView tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

            if(i>0){
                iv.setImageBitmap(bp);
                System.out.println("face ////////////////detectecd");
                tv.setText("faces detected "+i);
            }
            else{
                iv.setImageBitmap(bp);
                System.out.println("no face ////////////////detectecd");
                tv.setText("No face detected");
                System.out.print("hello world");
            }

        }catch(Exception e ){
            System.out.println("exception occured");
        }


    }
}
```

and activity_main is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="click to take the photo"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="onthetapbuttonclick"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="status"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:contentDescription="taken photo"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

now problem is when i click the image every thing work pretty fine.
if a face is detected then it will show the face detected + number of faces in the TextView and set the clicked pic in the ImageView and will print no face detected if face is not detected, but after that no statement is getting executed.
e.g in "no face ////////////////detected" is getting printed but "hello world " is not getting printed.
I have tried updating the TextView using a Thread. but problem persists 
I have tested it many times and both android studio for linux as well as for windows. Kindly help

Comment: you are talking about the log, aren't you?

Comment: of course .... System print statements will show in log cat

Comment: i have tested it properly using println even filtered the logcat with regular expression

Comment: from the terminal `adb logcat | grep -i "hello world"` does print anything?

Comment: no, thats what is happening most weird

Comment: in the first step i thought i might be due to openjdk in linux but i tested it on oracle jdk

Comment: Have you tried anything other than the print? A Toast, for example?

Comment: i had to call a method after that statement. my controll was not getting into that method then i tried printing a statement same happened ...then i updated the TextView using thread.. that also did not help..

Comment: problem is solved . i had to build a new project and copy all code to that project. it might be due to we are lacking clean and build in android studio. it was picking old classes